# Javascript how to escape characters

Tags: javascript

I want to insert some html into a div suppose this:

```
<div id="Sag">
 </div>
```

I am using `$('#Sag').html(data)`, in order to insert data into this div...
but here is the problem my data is:

```
<table style="direction: rtl;float:right;">
                    <?php $sess = isset(Yii::app()->session['cart']) ? Yii::app()->session['cart'] : '{}';
                        $ses = json_decode($sess, true);
                        foreach ($ses as $i=>$value11){
                        ?>
                <tr style="direction: rtl;" class="cart_show">
                     <td>
                         <img class="picCart-<?php echo $i; ?>" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/images/".$ses[$i]['properties']['pic_directory'];?>" width="100" heigh="100">
                     </td>
                    <td class="descCart-<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <?php echo $ses[$i]['properties']['description'];?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="priceCart-<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <?php echo $ses[$i]['properties']['price'];?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="quantityCart-<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <input type="text" style="width: 20px;" class="voroodi" value="<?php  
                        echo $ses[$i]['quantity'];
                        ?>">
                        <button name="delete_from_cart-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="btnDel">??? </button>
                        <button name="modify_cart-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="btnModify">?????</button>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                        </table>
```

so how can I escape `"`,`'`, ...? should I use a `\` before each one, or is there something like `@` in C# to use in javascript?

Comment: Your data is what? How are you getting that chunk of code?

Comment: What do you intend to happen when you it in the div. Note that the php will not execute as javascript is clientside.

Comment: the data is something that is using the session in order to show the user's cart, so is there any other idea for this purpose.
P.S: the content of the specified div would be shown to the user as a pop up window so I think it's my solution to show the user this content without reloading the page

Answer (score 8):

> so how can I escape ",',... should I use a \ before each one, or is there something like @ in c# to use in javascript

No, JavaScript doesn't have an equivalent of C#'s `@` feature.

In JavaScript, strings can be quoted by either single (`'`) or double (`"`) quotes. Within a quote, only the style you've used for quoting needs to be escaped. So within a string quoted with single quotes, double quotes don't need escaping; and within a string using double quotes, single quotes don't need escaping. (It's always *okay* to escape them, all that varies is whether you *have* to.)

So you usually pick the one you're using least, and use that for the main string's delimiter. E.g.:

```
str = "This uses doubles, so I don't have to worry about the ' in \"don't\".";
```

Note that I didn't have to escape `'` there, but I did have to escape `"`.

Similarly:

```
str = 'This uses singles, so I don\'t have to worry about "quoting" things.';
```

There I had to escape `'` but not `"`.